# PostgreSQL - Update view on given time

Tags: postgresql, view

Is it possible to update view table on specific interval? (For example every hour)
How can I do this?

Comment: You should define the view in a way that doesn't need regular redefinition. Perhaps you can edit the question and tell us more about your problem.

Comment: What do you mean with "update"? Change the underlying data? Change the _definition_ (i.e. the query) of the view?

Answer (score 0):

Postgres does not have an internal scheduler, so there is NO Direct method to do what you wanting. There are alternatives however. For Linux there is cron, pgAgent, and a Postgres extension pg_cron. For Windows there is Task Scheduler. Additionally, there are many commercial applications.